# How could I call Azure Maps API in C# with authorisation and client id?

Tags: c#, azure, api, azure-maps

I am trying to use **Azure Maps API** to search POIs around a point using its coordinates, and I do not know how to call the API by adding the **Authorization** and **client-id**.

This is the request preview I get when I try the API on the Microsoft documentation website.

```
GET https://atlas.microsoft.com/search/poi/json?api-version=1.0&query=university&lat=10.8232&lon=2.98234&limit=1

Authorization: Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1……

X-ms-client-id: SUXrtewLVItIG3X5…..
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use RestSharp. The authorization and client-id are added as header:

```
using RestSharp;

string url = $"https://atlas.microsoft.com/search/poi/json?api-version=1.0&query=university&lat=10.8232&lon=2.98234&limit=1";

var client = new RestClient(url);
var request = new RestRequest(Method.GET);

request.AddHeader("cache-control", "no-cache");
request.AddHeader("Authorization", “Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1……”);
request.AddHeader("X-ms-client-id", “SUXrtewLVItIG3X5…..”);

IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);

if (response.IsSuccessful)
{
    string content = response.Content;
}
```

Don't forget to start by installing the RestSharp NuGet package.

Answer (score 5):

There is an open source project that provides a .NET client for the Azure Maps REST services. There is a NuGet package too. You can find it here: https://github.com/perfahlen/AzureMapsRestServices The Azure Maps plans on also providing an official .NET client for the rest services later this year.

Comment: Is there an official .NET client now?

Comment: Not yet, but I believe on will be released soon and will likely be available here: https://azure.github.io/azure-sdk/releases/latest/all/dotnet.html